# xmllint: XML won't validate because of whitespace inserted by prettyprinter

Tags: xml, validation, scala, whitespace, pretty-print

I created a Scala application which reads information from a handful of sources and outputs it as an XML file, using `scala.xml.PrettyPrinter`. This file has to confirm to a XML Schema, because I also wrote an R script which will consume a file implementing the schema.

The schema contains a few enumerations, and the validation fails with messages like:

```
xmllint --noout studies-clean.xml --schema ../litsuche-satisfaction.xsd 
studies-clean.xml:
9: element satisfactionCorrelation: Schemas validity error : 
Element '{http://rumtscho/dissertation/litusersat}satisfactionCorrelation': 
[facet 'enumeration'] The value '
        observed user reactions
      ' is not an element of the set {'satisfaction', 'usability', 
'product quality', 'task process quality', 'absence of negative reactions', 
'task result quality', 'expectation disconfirmation', 'preference for a version', 
'enjoyment', 'observed user reactions', 'technology acceptance', 'likelihood of 
referral', 'user state', 'attribute performance', 'user choice of action', 'time 
spent doing a task', 'user's impression of the system', 'impact of IS', 
'user characteristics', 'organisation context', 'task parameters', 'need fit', 
'cost', 'cognitive load'}.
```

As you can see, `observed user reactions` is a member of my enumeration, but the same string with leading and trailing whitespace isn't getting recognized. This whitespace gets inserted by the pretty printer; another line where the value is `usability` gets printed on a single row, and the validator doesn't complain there.

Using the --noblanks option of xmllint doesn't change anything.

I don't know what to change so that the whole thing works. I see two alternatives:

1. I could stop using the pretty printer and instead use a formatter which removes all white space between elements from my Node before writing it to a file. This should validate, but if I ever have to open the file to check things manually, the absence of line breaks will be problematic.
2. I could try to rewrite the XML schema to accept whitespace before and after the text of an enumeration element.
3. I could try to somehow get xmllint to not pay attention to whitespace issues while validating.

Options 2 and 3 also require me to make R trim any text while loading, but this is a one-line change. So I strongly prefer to use one of them.

**My questions**:

1. Is option 3 possible at all? Does xmllint have an option to ignore whitespace while validating? If yes, how is it turned on? If no, is an alternative tool which can validate my file quickly with a shell command?
2. Is option 2 possible at all? Does XML Schema allow to mix a whitespace facet and an enumeration facet? (probably a newb question, but this is the first time I have ever written a schema)
3. Am I overlooking some drawback to Option 2 and/or 3 which would make Option 1 a better solution?

*update in response to a comment* This is the pretty printer output. It has inserted line breaks around the long value, but not around the short one. I think that this is normal behavior for a pretty printer, but even if it weren't, the API doesn't include an option to stop it from inserting these breaks.

```
<st:satisfactionCorrelations>
  <st:satisfactionCorrelation>
    observed user reactions
  </st:satisfactionCorrelation>
  <st:satisfactionCorrelation>usability</st:satisfactionCorrelation>
</st:satisfactionCorrelations>
```

Comment: Seems like your pretty print is wrong? pretty print should not place spaces inside the value of elements, which enums are. Can you show your XML&Schema?

Comment: @MarvinSmit it inserts line breaks after a tag, before the text in an element, and after the text, before the closing tag. The line breaks trip up the validator. Haven't checked if it inserts spaces too. But without line breaks, it wouldn't be a pretty printer.

Comment: Validator seems to complain about a enum value being invalid since there are spaces/linebreak in the value of the enum. You're xml will look like '<enumElement> {linebeak}
Value{linebreak}
           </enumElement>' Which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use Option 1 and use a pretty-printing filter whenever you want to view the file. For example

```
xmllint --format foo.xml|less
```

or

```
xmllint --format foo.xml > foo-pretty-printed.xml
```